# Rails jQuery: Check checkboxes when something is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a script that works when something is selected, a checkbox would be checked and some would be disabled. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myselect').change(function(){
        if (!$(this.val() == "0")){
            $('#boss').prop('checked', true);
            $('#manager').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#crew').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
})
</script>

<div>
  <%= f.label :company_code, "Company:" %>
  <select id="myselect">
    <option value = "0">Mcdo</option>
    <option value = "5">Burger King</option>
    <option value = "1">KFC</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
    Select Role:
</div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <p><%= f.check_box :boss, :id => 'boss' %>Boss</p>
    <p><%= f.check_box :manager, :id => 'manager' %>Manager</p>
    <p><%= f.check_box :crew, :id => 'crew' %>Crew</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: use `.prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myselect').change(function() {
    //you have an error here in closing the bracket,  also the condition is not proper
    if ($(this).val() != "0") {
      $('#boss').prop('checked', true);
      $('#manager').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#crew').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="0">Mcdo</option>
  <option value="5">Burger King</option>
  <option value="1">KFC</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="boss" />
<input type="checkbox" id="manager" />
<input type="checkbox" id="crew" />
```

You also might have to handle a case where those inputs has to be enabled, may be like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myselect').change(function() {
    var state = $(this).val() == "0";
    if (!state) {
      $('#boss').prop('checked', true);
    }
    $('#manager, #crew').prop('disabled', !state);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="0">Mcdo</option>
  <option value="5">Burger King</option>
  <option value="1">KFC</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="boss" />
<input type="checkbox" id="manager" />
<input type="checkbox" id="crew" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error in this line `if (!$(this.val() == "0")){` and change it to `if (!$(this).val() == "0") {`.